HTML Table buttons not working when adding data-toogle=table attribute
I have a table where I have added one button on each row and it was working fine.
Now I want that table to be searchable and sortable. For that I added the attribute data-toogle=table and the corresponding data-search="true" (on table level) and data-sortable="true" (on row level). The problem is that sort and search do not work if I do not add data-toogle=table, and when add it, buttons stop working.
Just removing the data-toogle=table, buttons work again, but table is not searchable and sortable anymore.
The script for the action of the button ("moreButton") is at the end part of the script.
My script including data-toogle=table (search and sort working but buttons don´t):
<html><head>
    <title>Compliance To-Dos - Overview</title>
<title>Generación PreInforme</title><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\bootstrap-table.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\styles.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\bootstrap.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\jquery-ui.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\jquery.dataTables.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\fontAwesomeIcons.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\chosen.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\select2.min.css"><link rel="stylesheet" href="..\..\..\style\css\select2-bootstrap4.min.css"><script src="https://code.iconify.design/1/1.0.5/iconify.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\jquery-3.5.1.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\tableExport.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\bootstrap-table.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\bootstrap-table-locale-all.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\bootstrap-table-export.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\jquery-ui.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\dataTables.bootstrap.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\moment.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\select2.min.js"></script><script src="..\..\..\javascript\js\chosen.jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.11/sorting/date-eu.js" type="text/javascript"></script><script>
        /*$(document).ready(
            var bootstrapButton = $.fn.button.noConflict();
            $.fn.bootstrapBtn = bootstrapButton;
        );*/
    </script></head>    
    
    <!--  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>-->

<body>

<nav role="navigation" class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="navbar-collapse" style="padding-left:5px;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="menu">
            <li><img class="fotoLogo" src="..\..\..\pictures\Picture1.png" alt="XYZ"></li>
            <li id="overview" class="botonNav active"><a href="..\compOverview\?filter=admin">To-Dos Overview</a></li>
            <li id="createToDo" class="botonNav"><a href="..\compCreateToDo\?filter=admin">Create New To-Do</a></li>
            <li id="deferment" class="botonNav"><a href="..\compDeferment\?filter=admin">Deferment Status</a></li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right alertInfo">
            <!-- If you see any of these values, you're probably having an error -->
            <li>User ID: <div name="userID" id="userID">admin</div></li>

        </ul>
    </div>  
</nav>

<script>

    //alert information
    //var userID = admin;

    //Navigation code
    var url = window.location;
    //to add new page in buttons: [subpage : $("#id_of_li_element")]
    var buttons = {
        "compOverview" : $("#overview"),
        "compCreateToDo" : $("#createToDo"),
        "compDeferment" : $("#deferment")
    };

    //$("#userID").html(userID);

    for(var key in buttons){
        if(isActive(key)){
            setActive(key);
        }
    }


    //***FUNCTIONS***//
    
    //returns true if the button's href is in the current URL
    function isActive(suffix){
        suffix = "/" + suffix;
        return url.href.indexOf(suffix) > -1;
    }

    //takes out "active" class from all elements
    function resetAll(){
        for(var key in buttons){
            buttons[key].removeClass("active");
        };
    }

    //sets a certain button "active" class
    function setActive(suffix){
        resetAll();
        buttons[suffix].addClass("active");
    }

</script>

    <!--<div id="tmep"></div>
    <script>
    console.log("");-->
    
    <div class="table-responsive">  
        <div id="hideableNotification">
            <table>
                <tbody><tr>
                    <td class="bell" style="text-align:left;">
                        <a href="/comp/compDeferment/?filter=admin">
                            <img src="../../../pictures/bell.png">Pending deferment approvals
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr><tr>
            </tr></tbody></table>
        </div>
        
        <div class="bootstrap-table bootstrap3">
      <div class="fixed-table-toolbar">
        <div class="pull-right search input-group">
          <input class="form-control
        
        search-input" type="search" aria-label="Soek" placeholder="Soek" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
      </div>
      
      <div class="fixed-table-container" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
      <div class="fixed-table-header" style="display: none;"><table></table></div>
      <div class="fixed-table-body">
      <div class="fixed-table-loading table table-bordered table-hover" style="top: 37.0667px;">
      <span class="loading-wrap">
      <span class="loading-text">Besig om te laai, wag asseblief</span>
      <span class="animation-wrap"><span class="animation-dot"></span></span>
      </span>
    
      </div>
      <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-bordered" id="expedientes" data-search="true" data-toggle="table">
        <!--Cabecera tabla-->
            <thead><tr class="h5"><th data-field="0"><div class="th-inner sortable both">BP</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="1"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Creation Date</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="2"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Last Update Date</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="3"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Due Date</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="4"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Escalation Level</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="5"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Communication Status</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="6"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Action Pending</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="7"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Reopen?</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th class="summarizedHead" data-field="8"><div class="th-inner sortable both">Details</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th><th data-field="9"><div class="th-inner ">+</div><div class="fht-cell"></div></th></tr></thead>
            <tbody><tr data-index="0"><td style="text-align:center;">12345</td><td style="text-align:center;">2024-05-31 14:23:52</td><td style="text-align:center;">2024-05-31 14:23:52</td><td style="text-align:center;">2024-06-13 00:00:00</td><td style="text-align:center;">Level 4</td><td style="text-align:center;">OPEN</td><td style="text-align:center;">No</td><td style="text-align:center;"><button class="" id="ActionButton0" style="display: none;">Reopen To-Do</button></td><td class="summarizedHead" style="text-align:center;"><div class="summarized"> Test for escalation time</div></td><td style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" id="moreButton" class="moreButton" aria-pressed="false">More</button></td></tr><tr id="table0" class="secondaryTable" style="display: none;" data-index="1"><td colspan="9"><table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Owner</th>
                                    <th>Details</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                    <th>Attachments Link</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>2024-05-31 14:23:52</td>
                                        <td>admin</td>
                                        <td>Test for escalation time</td>
                                        <td><button class="" id="respondButton0-0" style="">Actions</button></td>
                                        <td class=""></td>
                                        <script>                                            
                                            $(".respondButton").each(function(){
                                                $(this).hide();
                                                if($(this).attr("id") == null){
                                                    buttonID = "respondButton"+escalationNumber+"-"+messageNumber;
                                                    //$(this).hide();
                                                    $(this).attr("id",buttonID);
                                                    $(this).removeClass("respondButton");
                                                    if(true){
                                                        $(this).show();
                                                        $(this).click(function (e){
                                                            setResponseData($(this).attr("id"))
                                                            clickedRespond();
                                                            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                            $(".attachment").each(function(){
                                                var attachmentLink = "";
                                                if(attachmentLink != ""){
                                                    $(this).append("<a href=&#39;"+attachmentLink+"&#39; target=&#39;_blank&#39;><img class=&#39;linkIcon&#39; src=&#39;../../../pictures/link.png&#39;/></a>");
                                                }
                                                $(this).removeClass("attachment");
                                            });
                                            
                                            messageNumber++;
                                            
                                        </script>
                                    </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table></td></tr><tr data-index="2"><td style="text-align:center;">67890</td><td style="text-align:center;">2024-05-31 14:21:45</td><td style="text-align:center;">2024-05-31 14:21:45</td><td style="text-align:center;">2024-06-11 00:00:00</td><td style="text-align:center;">Level 4</td><td style="text-align:center;">OPEN</td><td style="text-align:center;">No</td><td style="text-align:center;"><button class="" id="ActionButton1" style="display: none;">Reopen To-Do</button></td><td class="summarizedHead" style="text-align:center;"><div class="summarized"> test</div></td><td style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" id="moreButton" class="moreButton" aria-pressed="false">More</button></td></tr><tr id="table1" class="secondaryTable" style="display: none;" data-index="3"><td colspan="9"><table class="table table-hover">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>Date</th>
                                    <th>Owner</th>
                                    <th>Details</th>
                                    <th>Actions</th>
                                    <th>Attachments Link</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>2024-05-31 14:21:45</td>
                                        <td>admin</td>
                                        <td>test</td>
                                        <td><button class="" id="respondButton1-1" style="">Actions</button></td>
                                        <td class=""></td>
                                        <script>                                            
                                            $(".respondButton").each(function(){
                                                $(this).hide();
                                                if($(this).attr("id") == null){
                                                    buttonID = "respondButton"+escalationNumber+"-"+messageNumber;
                                                    //$(this).hide();
                                                    $(this).attr("id",buttonID);
                                                    $(this).removeClass("respondButton");
                                                    if(true){
                                                        $(this).show();
                                                        $(this).click(function (e){
                                                            setResponseData($(this).attr("id"))
                                                            clickedRespond();
                                                            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
                                                        });
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                            $(".attachment").each(function(){
                                                var attachmentLink = "";
                                                if(attachmentLink != ""){
                                                    $(this).append("<a href=&#39;"+attachmentLink+"&#39; target=&#39;_blank&#39;><img class=&#39;linkIcon&#39; src=&#39;../../../pictures/link.png&#39;/></a>");
                                                }
                                                $(this).removeClass("attachment");
                                            });
                                            
                                            messageNumber++;
                                            
                                        </script>
                                    </tr>
                                
                            </tbody>
                        </table></td></tr></tbody>
        </table></div>
      <div class="fixed-table-footer"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fixed-table-pagination" style="display: none;"></div>
      </div><div class="clearfix"></div>
    </div>

<script>
    $(function () {
                $(".datepicker").datepicker({ dateFormat: "dd/mm/y",minDate: 0 });

    });
    $("input").each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $("#submit").show();
    $("#submit").attr('disabled',true);
    var status = $("#selectStatus").val();

    $("#selectStatus" ).change(function() {
            fillForm();

            var status = $("#selectStatus").val().toUpperCase();
            if(selectStatus.value == "DEFAULT"){
                $("#submit").attr('disabled',true);
            }else{
                $("#submit").attr('disabled',false);
            }     
        }
    );
    function onSubmit(){
        var status = $("#selectStatus").val();
        if(status != "default"){
            fillForm();
            $("#dialogConfirm").dialog("open");
        }
    }
    function clickedReopen(){
        fillForm();
        $("#formAction").attr('disabled',false);
        $("#formAction").val("REOPEN");
        $("#formAction").attr('disabled',true);
        $("#selectStatus").hide();
        $("#dueDate").show();
        $("#dueDateMessage").show();
        $("#submit").attr('disabled',false);
        $("#formReopenDueDate").show();
        $("#formReopenDueDateData")
    }
    function clickedRespond(){
        $("#selectStatus").val("DEFAULT");
        $("#message").val("");
        fillForm();
        $("#dueDate").hide();
        $("#dueDateMessage").hide();
        $("#selectStatus").show();
        $("#submit").attr('disabled',true);
        $("#formReopenDueDate").hide();
    }
    function fillForm(){
        var index = 0;
        
            if(index == currentEscalation){
                $("#formRequestID").val("613");
                $("#formMessage").val($("#message").val());
                $("#formOwner").val("admin");
                if( $("#formAction").val()!="REOPEN"){
                    $("#formAction").val($("#selectStatus").val());
                }
                $("#formReopenDueDateData").val($("#dueDate").val());

            }   
            index++;
        
            if(index == currentEscalation){
                $("#formRequestID").val("612");
                $("#formMessage").val($("#message").val());
                $("#formOwner").val("admin");
                if( $("#formAction").val()!="REOPEN"){
                    $("#formAction").val($("#selectStatus").val());
                }
                $("#formReopenDueDateData").val($("#dueDate").val());

            }   
            index++;
        
            
         
    }
    

    
</script>

<script>
var form = document.getElementById('hiddenForm');
form.action = '/api/comp/toDoResponse/?filter='+$('#userID').text();

$(".confirm").each(function(){
    $(this).attr("disabled",true);
});
function onConfirm(){
    $(".confirm").each(function(){
        $(this).attr("disabled",false);
    });
    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#confirmSubmit").one('click', function (event) {  
           event.preventDefault();
           //do something
           $(this).prop('disabled', true);
        });
    });
}
function onCancel(){
}

</script>


<script>

    $(function(){
        $("#dialog").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        width:700
            
        });
        $("#dialogConfirm").dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        modal: true,
                        width:700
        });
    })
    if(true){
        $("#hideableNotification").show();
    }else{
        $("#hideableNotification").hide();
    }

    
    var buttonNumber = 0;
    var tableNumber = 0;
    $(".secondaryTable").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('id', 'table' + tableNumber);
        tableNumber++;
        $(this).hide();
    });
    
    $(".moreButton").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('id', 'button' + buttonNumber);
        $(this).click(function(e){
            var id  = $(this).attr('id')
            var index =parseInt(id.replace("button",""));
            if($(this).text()=="More"){
                reset();
                $("#table"+index).show();
            }else{
                $("#table"+index).hide();
            }
            $(this).text($(this).text() == "More" ? "Less" : "More");
        });
        buttonNumber++;
    });

    function reset(){
        $(".secondaryTable").each(function(){
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $(".moreButton").each(function(){
            $(this).text("More");
        })
    }
    function setResponseData(buttonID){
        var indices =buttonID.replace("respondButton","");
        indices = indices.split("-");
        currentEscalation =parseInt(indices[0]);
        currentMessage = parseInt(indices[1]);

    }
    function setResponseReopen(buttonID){
        var index =buttonID.replace("ActionButton","");
        currentEscalation =parseInt(index);
    }

</script>

<div id="ui-datepicker-div" class="ui-datepicker ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all"></div><div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" aria-describedby="dialog" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="display: none; position: absolute;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle"><span id="ui-id-1" class="ui-dialog-title">Send new message</span><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button></div><div id="dialog" class="modal-dialog modal-lg ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <select id="selectStatus" class="form-control">
        <option value="DEFAULT">Select an option</option>
        <option value="CLOSE">Close To-Do</option>
        <option value="MAINTAINOPEN">Maintain this To-do open</option>
    </select>
    <div id="dueDateMessage">New Due Date</div>
    <input name="dueDate" id="dueDate" autocomplete="off" type="text" readonly="readonly" class="form-control datepicker hasDatepicker" style="display: none;">

    Message:
    <br>
    <textarea class="textarea" id="message" name="txtname" rows="10" cols="55"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input class="form-control" id="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return onSubmit()" disabled="disabled" style="">

    
</div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div><div tabindex="-1" role="dialog" class="ui-dialog ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-front ui-draggable ui-resizable" aria-describedby="dialogConfirm" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" style="display: none; position: absolute;"><div class="ui-dialog-titlebar ui-corner-all ui-widget-header ui-helper-clearfix ui-draggable-handle"><span id="ui-id-2" class="ui-dialog-title">Confirm data</span><button type="button" class="ui-button ui-corner-all ui-widget ui-button-icon-only ui-dialog-titlebar-close" title="Close"><span class="ui-button-icon ui-icon ui-icon-closethick"></span><span class="ui-button-icon-space"> </span>Close</button></div><div id="dialogConfirm" class="modal-dialog modal-lg ui-dialog-content ui-widget-content">
    <h3>You are about to submit this information:</h3>
    <form id="hiddenForm" action="/api/comp/toDoResponse/?filter=admin" class="form" method="post">
        <table>
            <tbody><tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Request ID:</td> 
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input id="formRequestID" class="confirm" type="number" name="requestID" disabled="disabled"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Owner of communication: </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input id="formOwner" class="confirm" type="text" name="owner" disabled="disabled"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Action taken: </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input id="formAction" class="confirm" type="text" name="action" disabled="disabled"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td style="text-align:center;">Message: </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input id="formMessage" class="confirm" type="text" name="detail" disabled="disabled"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="formReopenDueDate">
                <td style="text-align:center;">New Due Date: </td>
                <td style="text-align:center;"><input id="formReopenDueDateData" class="confirm" type="text" name="reopenedDueDate" disabled="disabled"></td>
            </tr>
             
            <tr>
            
                <td><input class="form-control" id="confirmSubmit" type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return onConfirm()"></td>
                <td><input class="form-control" id="confirmCancel" type="submit" value="Cancel" onclick="return onCancel()"></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody></table>
        </form>
</div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-n" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-e" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-s" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-w" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-se ui-icon ui-icon-gripsmall-diagonal-se" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-sw" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-ne" style="z-index: 90;"></div><div class="ui-resizable-handle ui-resizable-nw" style="z-index: 90;"></div></div></body></html>


why you are creating eventhandler for each button in a loop?

also id="moreButton2" class="moreButton2" created in loop on each button, resulting invalid html

check if this is working: https://jsfiddle.net/thn8kdmg/ (I have removed all other scripts, you need to add it by yourself again)

@Death-is-the-real-truth, sorry "moreButton2" was an error. The one I need and for which the script action was declared is "moreButton". I have included your $(".moreButton").click(function(e) but still not working. Table is sortable and searcheable having the data-toggle=table, but the buttons are still not doing anything.

Kindly update your question with the rendered HTML on the browser, not this coded one. that will helps us to check and resolve the issue. Update jquery code also incase you hide/remove something to make it short.

@Death-is-the-real-truth, I have updated my original comment with the rendered HTML, keeping only two rows of the main table for easiness. Many thanks in advance.
